# Storing a function reference with variable arguments in a data member in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

I want to store a function reference with a variable number of arguments in a class data member and call it later as follows:

```
auto my_action = new ExecuteAction("Add", add, 1, 2);
std::vector<ExecuteAction *> execute_actions;
execute_actions.push_back(my_action);
// ...
auto my_action_retrieved = execute_actions.at(0);
my_action_retrieved->execute();
```

Note that `add()` is e.g. defined as follows:

```
void add(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}
```

The closest solution I could get so far is the following:

```
template<typename Function, typename... Arguments>
class ExecuteAction {
    static_assert(!(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Arguments> && ...));

    std::string option_name;
    Function function;
    std::tuple<Arguments...> arguments;

public:
    template<typename ForwardFunction, typename... ForwardArguments,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<ForwardArguments &&, Arguments> && ...)>>
    explicit ExecuteAction(std::string &option_name,
                           ForwardFunction &&function,
                           ForwardArguments &&... arguments)
            : function(std::forward<ForwardFunction>(function)),
              arguments{std::forward<ForwardArguments>(arguments)...} {
        this->option_name = option_name;
    }

    void execute() {
        std::apply(function, arguments);
    }
};

template<typename Function, typename... Arguments>
auto make_execute_action(std::string option_name, Function &&function, Arguments &&... arguments) {
    return new ExecuteAction<std::decay_t<Function>, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arguments>>...>
            (option_name, std::forward<Function>(function), std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...);
}
```

This code can successfully be called as follows:

```
auto add_action = make_execute_action("Add", [](int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}, 1, 2);
add_action->execute();
```

**This solution however has the following problems:**

- Functions have to be passed by lambda expression but I want to pass function references (like in the example above)
- Using a generic `std::vector` doesn't seem possible since the template parameters need to be specifically defined

Is there an implementation in `C` or up till `C++20` which satisfies my requirements?

Comment: "Is there an implementation in C" ? C ? is this a typo?

Comment: @idclev463035818: No, I was thinking about `varags` which could theoretically be used as well

Comment: C++ has `var_args` too

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)? Of course, it requires all functions to have the same signature.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: But I want the arguments to be completely arbitrary in type and amount for passing to the function reference when executing the call

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: You need to clarify, then, what is inadequate about the `std::function`/`std::bind` (or `std::bind_front`) approach.

Comment: @DavisHerring: As I said, I want to pass arbitrary arguments and retain compiler checks based on the passed function reference instead of defining subclasses for each signature I may need. However, it seems like that is actually impossible.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: How does the suggested approach not let you “pass arbitrary arguments” and “retain compiler checks”, and how does it involve “defining subclasses”?  Maybe you want `std::reference_wrapper` too?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: `std::bind(add, 1, 2)` returns an object that can be assigned to `std::function<void()>`. All type safe. No lambdas required. `std::function<...>` objects are callable objects, but you don't need to write any boilerplate or subclasses.